# Geneos monitoring of IIS Application Pools

Tags: iis, geneos, itrs

I need to monitor iis app pools using itrs geneos and solution was to use the toolkit plugin to run a powershell script to run get -iisapppool and pipe the results to a csv for itrs to read. Works fine but my issue is i have some app pools running and some down on same server. I cant write a rule to differentiate as they all have startup mode of on demand.

I do the same for windows services but the rule works as i can say status is started and startup mode ia automatic=green or status is stopped and startup mode is manual = red.
I cant think of a iis equivalent.
i need to include those down as we can stop and start on different servers
Any ideas? or is there an alternative way to monitor the app pools.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to monitor the actual functionality and responsiveness of the application pool, rather than relying solely on the startup mode or state. You can write a custom PowerShell script to check if the application pool is responding to requests. If an application pool is not responding, it may be considered "down" regardless of its startup mode.